# Creating Handles to Custom Circle view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have Created Custom Circle View With this Code

```
//Color Declaration
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.429 blue:0 alpha:1];

    //Drawing Circle
    CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake(20, 20, 170, 170);
    UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [circlePath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(circleRect), CGRectGetMidY(circleRect))
                          radius:CGRectGetWidth(circleRect)/2 startAngle:0 * M_PI/180
                        endAngle:289 * M_PI/180
                       clockwise:YES];
    [circlePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(circleRect), CGRectGetMidY(circleRect))];
    [circlePath closePath];


    [color setFill];
    [circlePath fill];
```

I have Requirement were i have to re-size the start-Angle and End-Angle using Handles.
How to Create Handles around the Circle..?
How to Move Handles using Touches

Comment: may this could help http://developingios.blogspot.in/2013/04/uicircularprogress-bar-for-ios.html

Answer (score 0):

[SPUserResizableView](https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView) is a user-resizable, user-repositionable UIView subclass. Now obviously it isn't exactly what you need but looking at the code here, I'm sure you can figure out what you need for your app.

Just figure out where you want your anchor points to go, and then implement the handles.

Comment: Can you please check this out http://www.thinkandbuild.it/how-to-build-a-custom-control-in-ios/

Comment: we have to Change the Angles using handles

Comment: Doesn't the tutorial tell you how to do that?

Comment: No, I need to do Angle limiting

Comment: I am not Resizing the View, just rotating the handles to limit the angle of Circle